# Android 4.4 sdCard files can't be deleted?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-sdcard, delete-file

This question is asking many times but still I didn't get any answer. In my case application is not able to delete files from sdCard in OS 4.4 but many application like Es file explorer Clean master can delete it. 
Please help.

Comment: share  your code which you tried

Comment: i m tried with delete() , Content provider , also http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2634840

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can list your code so we can figure out why you can't delete a file. In my projects, I didn't have this trouble. Permissions missing or wrong path may cause this problem. And if you are reading the file (InputStream is not close), you'll not delete the file either.

Comment: try in OS 4.4 with Sdcard then let me know what is the result

Answer (score -1):

you might not have enough permission in your app like writing to external storage. You need to add this permission if your app targets below API 19. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE